# Hide individual UITableViewCell separator

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

Apart from removing all `UITableViewCell` separators using `tableView.separatorStyle = .None` or offsetting the individual separator using `cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 4500.0, 0.0, 0.0)` is there a way to remove a cells separator?

The first method affects all of the cells and the second method seems far too hacky, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Create your own separator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge this is the right way of doing it. You could use a custom cell to manage your own borders but that too would be like adding a border view and controlling it for the cells you want. To me, this is not a hack. There is no direct way given by Apple to do this but you can always utilise your language knowledge!

Comment: I see. I assumed that there would be some sort of finer control of these separators but apparently not. Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can add a subview in your custom cell as a seperator and hide/show as you like